# read.table acts differently when used in the console vs when used in an R markdown file

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to read in a file (pipe delimited) inside a code chunk in R markdown using RStudio. See below for the R markdown code chunk

````
```{r}
dealInfo <- read.table("deneme.dat",header=TRUE,sep="|",quote="",comment="",fill=TRUE)
dim(dealInfo)
```
````

The output

```
dealInfo <- read.table("deneme.dat", header = TRUE, sep = "|", quote = "", comment = "", 
fill = TRUE)
## Warning: invalid input found on input connection 'deneme.dat'
## Warning: incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'deneme.dat'
dim(dealInfo)
## [1]  1 50
```

The first line of the file has the word "Société". However, when I enter the commands in the console read.table reads all the lines in the file without any complaints. The "é" character when read into the data.frame is converted to "\xe9". The file deneme.dat contains three lines of data. When I have markdown print the contents of dealInfo I see that nothing after the first occurrence of "é" is read. This I believe explains the 2nd warning.

I am not sure why console and markdown behaves differently when reading the same file, it looks like the locale's and other configuration parameters are the same in both environments. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: looks like you need to set your local! what do you get when you type this in console  `read.table(text ='Société')`?

Comment: I get the word "Société" printed properly. Both in the console and markdown output.

Comment: For the warning 

        `incomplete final line found by readTableHeader`

 1. Open the file Go to to the last line, 
 2. Place the cursor the end of that line Press return Save the file

Comment: @agstudy, thanks,  I updated the question to address you previous comment.

Comment: Since you have just 3 lines can edit and add them to your question to reproduce the error?

Comment: @agstudy, In order to make the post reproducible I had looked into that. When I use cat("_lines_",file="deneme.dat") to write the lines into a file using R, and then read them back, it works. Due to this unexpected behavior I am not able to provide with a reproducible example. I didn't want to convolute the question by adding to many details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is a bug (about file encodings) which has been fixed a while ago in both RStudio and knitr. Please upgrade [RStudio (v0.97.316)](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/) and [knitr (v1.0.5)](http://cran.r-project.org/package=knitr), and see if the problem is still there. Also see [FAQ 1](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md) :)

At worst you can resave your Rmd document with the native encoding of your OS (`File => Save with Encoding`). The underlying reason of the problem you described is that RStudio was using `options(encoding = ...)` to declare the encoding of the document, but that was inappropriate because it changed the encoding of the whole R session (I confess this was due to my wrong instructions to them in the very beginning). Now RStudio is able to pass the encoding to `knitr` in a non-intrusive way.